# Schema import without a namespace-attribute

Tags: xml, import, namespaces, xsd, schema

Hy,

If i import a namespace like this:

```
<xs:import namespace="UniqueIRIstyleNameSpaceName" schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd"></xs:import>
```

I know that mySchema.xsd creates a targetNamespace="UniqueIRIstyleNameSpaceName".
Now if i go to: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_import.asp and read the according API of the 'import' element defined in the namespace bound to 'xs' it says the attribute 'namespace' is optional.

Now here are the questions:

- MUST the value of attribute 'namespace' of such an import always be the same as the value of 'targetNamespace' in the corresponding schema (.xsd)?
- If so: Wouldnt it be easier to just completly leave away the 'namespace' attribute at all?
- If not: ... Im in deep trouble since i seem to not have fully understood the namespace concept and would be realy interested in a few keywords where to look up information to close the leaks :)

I ask this because i am currently working with XML/ XSDs for like the 5th time in my career and never seen it in another variation but 'namespace' attribute always there and matching 'targetNamespace's value in the according schema.

Many thanks in advance & regards

Jba

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> MUST the value of attribute 'namespace' of such an import always be the same as the value of 'targetNamespace' in the corresponding schema (.xsd)?

Yes, absolutely.
You cannot redefine the target namespace of the imported schema!

That is possible indeed, but using `<xs:include>` and only when the included schema has no target namespace.
Such a technique is called "chameleon design".

> If so: Wouldnt it be easier to just completly leave away the 'namespace' attribute at all?

No. The only case when you should omit `namespace` attribute is when the imported schema
has no target namespace. That is, its target namespace is the global one.

In `<xs:import>` the `namespace` attribute is the primary one. Specifying the imported namespace may be just enough for a schema processor to import the necessary schema. The `schemaLocation` is rather a hint where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ColdFusion's answer:

1. xs:include must be child element of xs:schema, and is for one schema to include a fragment defined in another file, with either same or no target namespace
2. note also for XML documents to include a schema reference, this is done via attribute on the root node; the namespace half of the schemaLocation is required, but what if the target schema is a fragment without targetnamespace specified? then you can define whichever namespace you like e.g.

   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="anyNameSpaceYouWant .\SampleLocalFile.xsd"

(Tested with Visual Studio 2019 built-in XML validator)

references:
https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_howto.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp